# Skipping every nth row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, slice

I am trying to slice my dataframe by skipping every 4th row. The best way I could get it done is by getting the index of every 4th row and then selecting all the other rows. Like below:-

`df[~df.index.isin(df[::4].index)]`

I was wondering if there is a simpler and/or more pythonic way of getting this done.

Comment: One alternative: `df = df.drop(df.iloc[::4].index, 0)`

Comment: Try this: `df[(df.index+1)%4!=0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is create mask by modulo and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10, 30)}, index=range(20))
#print (df)


b = df[np.mod(np.arange(df.index.size),4)!=0]
print (b)
     a
1   11
2   12
3   13
5   15
6   16
7   17
9   19
10  20
11  21
13  23
14  24
15  25
17  27
18  28
19  29
```

**Details**:

```
print (np.mod(np.arange(df.index.size),4))
[0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3]

print (np.mod(np.arange(df.index.size),4)!=0)
[False  True  True  True False  True  True  True False  True  True  True
 False  True  True  True False  True  True  True]
```

If unique index values use a bit changed @jpp solution from comment:

```
b = df.drop(df.index[::4], 0)
```